# Why don't the students of Hogwarts write with ballpoint pens?

Tags: harry-potter

I understand that modern technology cannot be used in Hogwarts.  The magic interferes with such muggle devices.  But why can't they use a Biro?

I weep for the left-handed witches and wizards who have to use those feather quills and ink pots to write, and it all seems so unnecessary.  A Biro is not like a TV or a toaster.  It is a simple device utilizing gravity fed ink to coat a ball bearing with a thin coat of ink, allowing for easy writing.  I see no reason why it wouldn't work in Hogwarts, so why do they insist on using feather quills?

Comment: Quills are cooler. They also contribute to a distinction between the magic world and the Muggle world. And left-handers can write with quills (and I've had problems enough writing with a biro).

Comment: They're cooler is you are not a lefty.  Speaking as a member of the sinister caste, the ink smudging would be ghastly.  Maybe some lefty's are fortunate enough to be able to work around this problem, but the point stands.  When your hand is moving towards the ink rather than away for the ink, you want a little wet ink on the page as possible.

Comment: I'm also a lefty and I know the problems you're talking about. There are standard workarounds and I've used them. It's not a huge deal once you get used to them (I use and enjoy a fountain pen, and I've had smudge problems even with biros.)

Comment: Are students allowed to use biros in English schools now? I remember when I was growing up, we had to use fountain pens (cartridge type, not manual fill). Biros (ball-point pens) were not allowed. The lefties I knew either used that weird, cramped, reach over the top technique, or wrote fairly normally and had worked out ways to not smudge the ink. Taking a couple more backward steps in technology fits the Hogwarts aesthetic.

Comment: Obviously they use ink enchanted to not smudge instead.

Comment: @JAB That was what I was about to say too. Or they use a spell to remove all the smudges.

Comment: Similar to @Dranon’s experience, we were only allowed fountain pens at my elementary school in Germany in the 90s. And I *think* high school (same decade) at least discouraged ballpoint, if not forbidding it outright (but I’m not sure about that). So I don’t find it at all odd that an even marginally traditional school (and Hogwarts is *very* traditional) would ban modern writing implements. And as for fountain pen vs quill, well, the difference is really minor once a magical ink reservoir comes into play.

Comment: I could see the use of a quill if you wanted to create a scroll imbued with magic where that required mixing custom inks. (I don't recall magical scrolls, but it's been years since I read HP.) As for sinister, I knew a woman who would stare at the paper for a few minutes, working it all out in her head, then write it backwards from right to left. More for bragging rights than any real utility, but it looked damn impressive.

Comment: As @Dranon says, it is the æsthetic wot mandates it.

Comment: (No canon for this, so just a comment). We see many anachronistic things in the magical world including clothing. However, there are still things like quills, spectacles and desks that probably can be substituted by "pure magic" (if they chose to). I think there was basically a "divergence" or parting of ways between the Muggle and Magical worlds that explains this. A likely cutoff is c.1692, when the Int'l Statute of Secrecy was implemented. The "Muggle tech" you see dates mostly before that. After that cutoff, more modern advances either never "came across" or did so very selectively/slowly.

Comment: Maybe lefties just use more blotting paper?

Comment: @Dranon yeah use ballpoint pens now (I was born in 1990). Only time I ever used a fountain pen was in year 6 when we were all given one to practice handwriting. But we still used ballpoint pens as well.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure everything used in Hogwarts is produced in the magical world, possibly using (you're not going to believe it) magic. As such, I don't think wizards *can* produce ballpoint pens, because that would require them to follow some advancements in technology, which they famously don't do. Remember Mr. Weasley, and how everyone thinks he's a wacko.

My point is - the supplies in magical world (including stationery) must be produced magically due to wizards' alienation from Muggles; I'm not saying a pen *wouldn't* work, I'm simply saying wizards wouldn't *think* of using one. Or chalk it up to quill-makers' lobby.

As to why Muggle-borns don't use them - what if they do? Since the series is centered very narrowly on the trio, there's not much room for others' perspective. Maybe some Muggle-borns do use them, we just don't see it (observer bias). There's also the problem of anti-Muggle sentiment, which seems to exist even in late 90s when the series is set. I assume showcasing one's Muggle-bornness would not be a very wise choice, especially with Voldemort's growing influence in later books.

The issue of wizarding pride is mentioned in the [Pottermore article on technology](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/technology), written by J. K. Rowling:

> There is another reason for most wizards' avoidance of Muggle devices, and that is cultural. The magical community prides itself on the fact that it does not need the many (admittedly ingenious) devices that Muggles have created to enable them to do what can be so easily done by magic. To fill one's house with tumble dryers and telephones would be seen as an admission of magical inadequacy.

I'm guessing a quill and an ink bottle are also easier to use in conjunction with magic - one can enchant the quill to write, regularly dipping itself in ink, and maybe sharpen itself. How does one refill a ballpoint pen? I don't. I throw it away, and get a new one; or if I really like it, I get a new core and change them. But the core of a pen is the part that is actually the hardest to make, what with the small ball, tiny tube, and the ink. The schematics of a quill are just simpler.

And why stop on pens? Why not use A4 paper, like normal people do, instead of parchment (and why not measure the parchment in metres, like normal people do, instead of feet)? I'm guessing the scope of possible improvements is too wide, and people just don't care.

One could also point out that glasses, watches, and some other tools *are* used by wizards. I'm guessing that is due to them being invented before the International Statute of Secrecy, which was accepted in 1692.

The Hogwarts Express is a notable Muggle invention that is being used by Wizards. However, this one is very much an edge case. As it is explained in [its Pottermore article](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express) written by J. K. Rowling, the train was the best option possible when it came to transporting a lot of students at one time, while still being hidden from Muggles. Multiple solutions, including various flying transportation methods, portkeys, and sometimes Apparition were tried, and some were meant to be tried but were blocked by the Headmasters of Hogwarts as breaching the security of the castle. In the end, it took a Muggle-curious Minister of Magic, "one hundred and sixty-seven Memory Charms and the largest ever mass Concealment Charm performed in Britain" to steal the train and put it to use. It was by no means easy, and definitely met opposition at the time:

> The Hogwarts Express underwent several magical modifications before the Ministry approved it for school use. Many pure-blood families were outraged at the idea of their children using Muggle transport, which they claimed was unsafe, insanitary and demeaning; however, as the Ministry decreed that students either rode the train or did not attend school, the objections were swiftly silenced.

There's also the problem of very few Muggle-borns, who would know about pens, being in charge of things. Sure, some students are Muggle-borns, but how many of the Ministry officials, or even the Hogwarts staff, are also Muggle-born? I would assume a Muggle-born taking over the ministry could change things for the best, but that would require a sequel to the seven *Harry Potter* books, and *we haven't gotten one*.

There is also a relevant [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-wizards-in-the-Harry-Potter-world-simply-use-a-pen-instead-of-a-quill-and-ink-bottle), which says more or less the same things, and maybe more.

Comment: I am fairly certain that not everything in Hogwarts is magically produced.  Harry's glasses were muggle made and, much like a Biro, operate on a simple principle of physics.  I doubt that the muggle-born students have to buy an all new wardrobe (specifically civilian clothes) because the zippers on their jeans cannot function in Hogwarts' magic field.

Comment: Your extra points were most enlightening.  I still think it's weird, cause the anti-muggle sentiment does not seem to extend to the student's civilian wear.  Honestly, I think the real reason is purely cosmetic.  Feather quills give the magical world a ancient feel.  I just like looking for an in-universe explanation for these things.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster Maybe biros don't write well on parchment?

Comment: Notice that Dumbledore's glasses and other glasses in the series arent made the same way as Harry's--they are more old-fashioned.

Comment: I think what we are all learning from this is that the magic of Hogwarts goes by the "do as I say, not as I do" rule

Comment: I think the key point in all this was made by Gallifreyan in the answer: Muggle technology is considered a clever little way of copying what can already be done with magic. We can probably assume that quills are magically improved and that a pen - invented much later - just isn't necessary. Plus, a quill is much cooler! If you were a Muggle-born who just enrolled, would you be wanting a little plastic biro?

Comment: These comments were getting a bit long and repetitive, so I've [moved them to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61189/discussion-on-answer-by-gallifreyan-why-dont-the-students-of-hogwarts-write-wit), where you can all continue the discussion for as long as you like.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster The "civilian clothing" that looks Muggle-ish is a movie thing, probably to make the characters more relatable on screen.  I am unaware of any mention of jeans in the books.

Comment: @Yakk Off the top of my head, see the seventh book where Hermione packs Ron's(?) too-small jeans. And i'm fairly sure there were many other cases mentioning pants pockets.

Comment: @Scimonster - In the books, almost all mention of any character's clothes is as robes. It struck me clearly when I recently reread all seven. However, once or twice it mentions Ron's or other young characters jeans.

Comment: I just noticed (after typing out my comment) that you'd already made the point about the International Statute of Secrecy in your answer. Glad that you think this as well.

Comment: +1 for 'I'm reasonably sure everything used in Hogwarts is produced in the magical world, possibly using (you're not going to believe it) magic.' A laugh is always welcome but particularly at this time in my life.

Comment: @Scimonster Well, in the seventh book, the trio is running first around London and then around the country-side, hiding from both muggles and wizards. Jeans make a lot of sense if you're trying not to look suspicious to all those Death Eaters. Needless to say, the films make almost everyone wear muggle clothing most of the time - it's not nearly as weird to read about people wearing (almost identical) robes all the time as actually seeing it on TV :P

Answer (score 16):

[A ballpoint pen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballpoint_pen) is not as simple a device as you assume.

> The manufacture of economical, reliable ballpoint pens as we know them arose from experimentation, modern chemistry, and precision manufacturing capabilities of the early 20th century.

Comment: It's time for you to [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). You clearly are active on the site and would like to participate. Whatever the circumstance you were a victim of was it's been forgotten. Come back to us.

Comment: Whilst they may be difficult to produce, the principle under which they operate is no more complicated than an hourglass.  It is the practical application of the principle of gravity.  There is no reason why an hourglass would be able to work in Hogwarts, but a Biro would not work.

Comment: @Edlothiad the web never forgets. It only buries stuff under more content.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster Really? What makes you so sure that it's just *gravity* that makes a pen work? Have you ever tried making your own pen? What keeps the ink from leaking out? What keeps it from making the ball too sticky to roll?

Comment: The ball bearing is tightly held in it's casing.  The casing prevents surplus ink from being released.  It's just like roll on deodorant (the type with a ball, not the stick type).  Dear Lord, does deodorant work in Hogwarts?

Comment: Probably not the ball type ;)

Comment: Maybe they are like hippies and they just rub crystals on their arm pits.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster see http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-38566114 . Ball point pens balls are hard.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster The kids get their supplies from Diagon Alley or Hogwarts itself. So "difficulty of manufacture" is very relevant - wizards certainly don't make ball-point pens, muggles do. And the two economies are repeatedly shown as almost entirely disconnected (including e.g. the price ratio of gold vs. silver being vastly different and *fixed*, which you could exploit to make yourself richer than any wizard). Wizards seem to distance themselves from muggles as much as possible; even the "pro-muggle" wizards (like Mr. Weasley) are mostly clueless about how muggles actually live.

Comment: @Luaan you could really work the gold/silver arbitrage, especially if  you could port to [Azeroth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Warcraft_locations#Azeroth).  There, [silver bars](http://www.wowuction.com/us/hakkar/horde/Items/Stats/2842#tabs=0) are at par with [gold bars](http://www.wowuction.com/us/hakkar/horde/Items/Stats/3577).

Comment: @KyleStrand: It's not *just* gravity, but gravity is an important part of making a normal ball-point pen work.  See [this article about NASA's development of a pen that can write in zero-G](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen/).  TL:DR: pressurize with nitrogen at 35PSI.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I understand that gravity is *part* of how ballpoint pens work. That is not the point of my comment.

Comment: VictimOfCircumstance, @PeteKirkham 's BBC link is probably worth adding to your answer. China is *far, far* more advanced in "muggle" technology than the wizards of Harry Potter are, and they've struggled to produce ballpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Gallifreyan has a very thorough answer but it doesn't cover one thing, the use of such technology outside of Hogwarts.

At the beginning of *The Prisoner of Azkaban* Harry is doing his homework in bed under the covers at night with an electric torch (let's ignore the breaking of the use of underage magic law that happens in the film) yet is still using a quill and ink pot. This seems **really** impractical.

He is nowhere near Hogwarts, so there can be no magical restriction on using a pen.

So at a guess of an in-universe answer, we could assume that (like some schools) Hogwarts insists on students using a proper pen (in this case a quill)

Answer (score 0):

Charms, spells, etc. can be placed on quills in the magical world such as anti cheating charms used during exams. Ink can also have special properties. This may not be possible for ballpoint pens in addition to points other have brought up regarding their non magical manufacture.

Comment: What would make a ball point pen different from a quill in this sense?

Comment: "Magic"... 

I don't think anyone* in the world, fictional or real knows the precise rules of Harry Potter magic so it could be any number of reasons.

Perhaps the specific spells are calibrated to work precisely with a quill's shape/materials/concept.
Perhaps all quills, or the ink therefor produced by the magical community are spelled on manufacture to allow those sorts of spells to be bolted on.

*With the probable exception of Harry James Potter-Evans-Verres